# "unknown blob" errors while pulling new images from Artifactory

Tags: artifactory

We have been getting "unknown blob" errors for the last two days when pulling from Artifactory. I am attaching a sample log:

```
Command ['ssh', '-o', 'StrictHostKeyChecking=no', '-o', 'LogLevel=ERROR', 'localhost', 'docker', 'pull', '<redacted>.jfrog.io/<redacted>:latest'] failed with exit code 1 and output 'latest: Pulling from <redacted>
f5d23c7fed46: Pulling fs layer
3f4aa1d1dde5: Pulling fs layer
52c4bf0b6229: Pulling fs layer
fe61f8f5a308: Pulling fs layer
ebeed9e8b27e: Pulling fs layer
89831686aa31: Pulling fs layer
2e2c5baec652: Pulling fs layer
b6fa760c79e4: Pulling fs layer
2e2c5baec652: Waiting
ebeed9e8b27e: Waiting
b6fa760c79e4: Waiting
fe61f8f5a308: Waiting
3f4aa1d1dde5: Verifying Checksum
3f4aa1d1dde5: Download complete
f5d23c7fed46: Verifying Checksum
f5d23c7fed46: Download complete
fe61f8f5a308: Download complete
ebeed9e8b27e: Download complete
89831686aa31: Download complete
f5d23c7fed46: Pull complete
3f4aa1d1dde5: Pull complete
2e2c5baec652: Verifying Checksum
2e2c5baec652: Download complete
b6fa760c79e4: Downloading
unknown blob
```

This seems to have started during the kinesis outage. We first noticed it while we were trying to deploy a workaround during the outage. However the problem still persists.

The image pulls fine from docker hub, so it's not corrupted. This is currently breaking out automated deploy/provisioning process, as we have manually pull failed imaged from dockerhub.

Comment: Assuming you are pulling this image in from a remote due to this sentence:
"The image pulls fine from docker hub, so it's not corrupted."
You may have pulled in a bad layer during the kinesis outage somehow.
Have you tried to clear the image? Log in to Artifactory or through the REST API and delete this image and re-pull it. This might work as it will cause it to pull from the remote which has a valid copy.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Yes, the image is pulled on remote clients.

I get the same behaviour on existing instances, as well as on newly provisioned ones, so it's likely not on the client side. I will try out the suggestion of removing the image from JFrog. We've seen this with "new" images too (build and pushed in the last 12 hours), but it might an older layer that is causing the issue.

Answer (score 2):

With @John's suggestion, I zapped the cache on JFrog side, and that removed the issue.

It seems that it's stale/invalid cache issue.

Also, while looking at the JFrog logs, I did find this, which might be relavant:

```
2020-11-28T18:55:24.493Z [jfrt ] [ERROR] [b66d3ae308977fb1] [o.a.r.RemoteRepoBase:858      ] [ttp-nio-8081-exec-17] - IO error while trying to download resource '<redacted>: org.artifactory.request.RemoteRequestException: Error fetching <redacted>/blobs/sha256:9c11dabbdc3a450cd1d9e15b016d455250606d78eecb33c92eebfa657549787f (remote response: 429: Too Many Requests)
```

TL;DR: zapping the cache fixed the problem.

Comment: Hello.how can I zap the cache of Jfrog?